# Location service in application class. Bad Practice?

Tags: android

This is a pretty straightforward question.  With the new background restrictions in oreo, we're removing the location background service and looking for ways to keep location services running when the app is in the background.

According to the dev docs, we can still get location updates, just less frequent, when the app is in the background BUT we can't tie the logic to any activity because we switch through activities in-app too often.

So my question is:  Would putting the location logic in the application class be a BAD thing?

disclaimer:  We have an ongoing notification as a foreground service, we're simply designing a use case where the user has disabled that ongoing notification.  We don't want to run the location logic in a foreground service as that just replaces 1 ongoing notification with another

Comment: When the user disables your ongoing notification option, does the user still need any updates to location when in background? You best bet is to start listening to location when your app is in the foreground, might not be as "fresh" as it used to be, but that okay

Comment: The app provides weather alerts based on location is 'current location' is set.  So yes, even without the ongoing notification, we need to stay pretty close to the user's actual location.  We typically update the location about once an hour when the app is in the background

Comment: Then the application class won't help all that much, your process can still be killed, you need some sort of combination of passive provider and JobScheduler to schedule getting a fix every specific period, or according to some conditions (charging.. etc)

Comment: yeah... I'm currently trying with firebase jobScheduler but the interval is so inconsistent.  I set it to 15 minutes and I see the intervals as 15, 5, 5, 10, 15, 6

Comment: That's the whole idea, it groups multiple jobs to batch them together, you save resources but you get little inaccuracy which might be okay, do you mind getting the update few minutes earlier/later than you needed? Since it's not an alarm, it should be okay.

Comment: I really don't mind.  My concern is with battery life.  I don't want to be pinging the gps every 5 minutes

Comment: You could have higher tolerance for [latency](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html?utm_campaign=adp_series_job_scheduler_092216&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog#setMinimumLatency%28long%29) and [deadline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html?utm_campaign=adp_series_job_scheduler_092216&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog#setOverrideDeadline%28long%29)

Comment: My only concern here is "Because it doesn't make sense setting this property on a periodic job, doing so will throw an IllegalArgumentExceptionwhen build() is called.". So won't this pop the exception if I'm setting up a repeating job?